# R: Transform data, like Excel Pivot table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I am struggling to transform my data to the below output. The output values are the sum of count.

Suspect this will involve a combination of `group_by()`,`pivot_wider()`, and
`summarise()`, but haven't had luck with that.

Data:

```
df1 <- rbind(animal.boolean = c("Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","N"),
             animal.detailed = c("cat", "mouse", "dog", "mouse", "cat", "dog", "cupboard"), 
             count = c(2,1,4,1,8,1,1))
```

Output:

```
df2 <- rbind(c(10,2,5,0), c(0,0,0,1))
colnames(df) <- c("cat", "mouse", "dog", "cupboard")
rownames(df) <- c("Y","N")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That matrix is truly bad input format. We can transpose it and turn it to a data frame, and then use `pivot_wider`'s `value_fn` argument to skip the need for a separate `group_by() %>% summarize()` step.

```
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
t(df1) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  type_convert() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = animal.detailed,
    values_from = count,
    values_fill = 0,
    values_fn = sum
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#   animal.boolean   cat cupboard   dog mouse
#   <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Y                 10        0     5     2
# 2 N                  0        1     0     0
```

Comment: Curious, how would you have structured df1?  @Gregor Thomas

Comment: @user15852004 I think if you initially structure `df1` to be in the form of `t(df1)`, then you would have 1 row for each observation. It's a little more tidy that way, and much easier to read.

Comment: @user15852004 Data is usually organized so each row is an observation and each column has a particular data type or class - you might have a column of numbers, a column of text, etc. R data frames are built this way, but it is not R-specific: databases are structured this way, Python data frames are this way, etc. It's unusual and difficult to work with when you mix data types in the same column - and your columns have different data types in every row.